# Ruby: Writing a Looping Program that Runs until resources are exhausted?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program in Ruby that will assess how many bottlecaps a person can trade in for an extra soda, and how long they can keep going until they can't trade any more in
I'm having a hard time visualizing how this is going to work. But here is what I have so far.

Rules:

```
User currently has 10 bottlecaps
They can trade in 3 bottlecaps to get a soda
User trades in 9/10 bottlecaps to get 3 extra sodas
Now they have 4 bottlecaps (1 left over and the 3 that were traded in)
They can trade in 3 more bottlecaps to get one extra soda
Now they have 1 bottlecap, and cannot trade in anymore
```

Here's what I have so far

```
bottlecaps = 10
for_trade = 3
traded_sodas = bottlecaps / for_trade
num_bottlecaps_traded = for_trade * traded_sodas
bottlecaps = bottlecaps - num_bottlecaps_traded
```

But I need to figure out how to get this to loop until the user can no longer trade bottlecaps. Can anyone give any pointers?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby can loop forever like this

```
loop do
  # code in here runs over and over again
end
```

To stop the loop, you can use the `break` keyword and check for some condition that indicates the loop should end, in your case

```
loop do
  break if bottlecaps < for_trade
  # trade bottlecaps...
end
```

A more concise way to write this kind of loop, where you check a condition before each repetition, is with `until`

```
until bottlecaps < for_trade
  # trade bottlecaps
end
```

or if you like thinking more positively

```
while bottlecaps >= for_trade
  # trade bottlecaps
end
```